# Make responsive text on the right and left side of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a slider using jQuery UI. The slider works well enough but I'm having a hard time making it responsive. I am trying to have labels on the right and left side. I've been able to accomplish this however I'm having lots of trouble making it responsive. How would I keep the lable's in the left and right corners of the screen regardless of the screen size?

Thanks for any help!

Here is the basic set up and a JsFiddle

```
 $("#slider2").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: -3,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#score2").val(ui.value);
            $(this).css("background", ui.value>0?"#2ecc71":ui.value<0?"#e74c3c":"");
            console.log(ui.value)
        }
    });



$("#slider3").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: -3,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#score3").val(ui.value);
            $(this).css("background", ui.value>0?"#2ecc71":ui.value<0?"#e74c3c":"");
            console.log(ui.value)
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lks94utg/

Comment: You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tdqjfv4f/ But I'm sure there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @Titus Write that as an actual answer and I'll mark is correct. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Be aware that this isn't a good responsive, right text will overlap input if width is too small

Comment: @PoprostuRonin Thanks for the advise! In order to make this work I set up media size devices to have a smaller input size. Seems to be fully responsive now!